# Django Rest Framework - Field username with ".", "-", "_" character

Tags: python, regex, django, django-rest-framework, django-users

I want allow from my backend API, that any user can be created with characters like `.`,`-`,`_`, `ñ` between others characters in their `username` field which is `primary_key=True,`.

I define my custom user (`AbstractBaseUser`) of this way, in relation to `username` field which is of my interest:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=30,
        primary_key=True,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                _('Enter a valid username. This value may contain only '
                  'letters, numbers ' 'and @/./+/-/_ characters.')
            ),
        ],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    objects = UserManager()
```

My `UserSerializer` is this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all(), message='Lo sentimos, existe un fichaje con este nombre de usuario')])
    email = serializers.EmailField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all(), message='Lo sentimos, alguien ya ha sido fichado con este correo electrónico')])

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'password', 'first_name','last_name',
                  'age','other fields ...',)
```

My UserViewSet is the following:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_fields = ('username', 'is_player', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'team' , 'email', )
```

The router is defined og this way in urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
```

When I create an user with `.` character for example like `bacalao.cevichica` in te `username` field, the user is created, but when I go to `localhost:8000/api/users/`

I get this message:

```
File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/fuupbol2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 392, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'user-detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 'bacalao.cevichica'}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['api/users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'api/users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$']
```

[image]

I am not very familiarized with the regular expresions, and is possible that the `RegexValidator` is not well formed?

Also, is possible that my problem is in the `UserSerializer` or `UserViewSet`.

By the moment I have not clear this topic, any orientation is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: It just sounds like the URL pattern doesn't support periods. Can you include the regex it's using in plaintext?

Comment: @TankorSmash in theory the regex which I am using is the code section of `RegexValidator(
                r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                _('Enter a valid username. This value may contain only '
                  'letters, numbers ' 'and @/./+/-/_ characters.')
            ),` in the username field in model User ... ? My apologies, I am newbie with regular expressions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the error you'll notice that it tried to match against some url, but failed. This is because the default regex `([^./])` excludes `.` and `/` characters

You can add a `lookup_value_regex` to your ViewSet so that the URL knows what format your primary key should be in:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    lookup_value_regex = '[\w.@+-]+'
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_fields = ('username', 'is_player', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'team' , 'email', )
```